# My model field gives me Value u'0' is not a valid choice error?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

```
FOOBAR = (
    (0, 'foo'),
    (1, 'bar'),
)

class Foobaz(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=FOOBAR, \
                                       verbose_name=_('foobar type'))

class FoobazForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Foobaz
        fields = ('type')
```

In views `foo_form = FoobazForm(request.POST)`
When I do `foo_form.is_valid()` It gives me validation error `u'0' is not a valid choice`.
Where I am doing something wrong?

Comment: In your `FoobazForm`'s inner `Meta`, you should have a comma in your fields definition, otherwise it isn't a tuple: `fields = ('type',)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I know about `django` is that it is a candidate for least euphonous package name of the decade, so this is a guess:

Users key in characters, not integers, so you should use:

```
FOOBAR = (
    ('0', 'foo'),
    ('1', 'bar'),
    )
```

**Update** Google is our friend: Here's [some seemingly relevant documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#field-choices).